# The bucket requested does not exist

Tags: php, database, laravel, couchbase

I am new to Couchbase and I am still studying it. I am using Laravel as my backend and also using this package: https://github.com/ytake/Laravel-Couchbase

Problem is I don't understand where to check my error. I have:

```
The bucket requested does not exist.
```

I want to query the default database that comes in couhbase which is `_users`.

I have this query:

```
\DB::connection('couchbase')->table('_users')->where('_id', '_design/_auth')->get();
```

I searched on the internet and found out that bucket is equivalent to database. I know MySQL though. So I checked the Admin Page of my Couchbase:

[image]

Then inside `_users`

[image]

and inside the first record:

[image]

My connection string:

```
'couchbase' => [
        'driver' => 'couchbase',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1:5984?detailed_errcodes=1',
        'user' => 'joene',
        'password' => 'CheRambil27',
    ],
```

I know there is something wrong with my query but I don't know where to check things. For example where do I declare bucket that I am querying to? If I want to query all the records in the `_users` bucket what would be the query? And for table, which should be my table name? Cooz I know `_users` is the database name right?

Comment: What is `:5984` referring to? the port should remain empty as the host likely refers to a Couchbase cluster node. The underlying Couchbase SDK should discover the appropriate port.